# Search & replace regex - filtering files

Tags: regex, replace

*little bit of background:*
I work at a multilingual communication company, where we’re working with a CMS system. Since its last update, all the files I export out of the system are ‘polluted’ with metadata, which I don't want to see, use or replace. To filter and change a heap of xml files, I use Powergrep, which operates with regexes.

I **want** my regex to find, e.g. "there is no spoon", "oracle", "I know kung-fu" and "bending method" (all straight quotation marks) and replace it with “there is no spoon”, “oracle”, “I know kung-fu” and “bending method” (all with curly quotation marks).

I **don’t want** it to find the metadata `"concept.dtd"` and `"map.dtd"` 
The following lines are the first lines of my xml file. It's this `"concept.dtd"` that I would like to ignore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd"[
]>
<?ish ishref="GUID-6B84EF92-DA99-4C54-BA91-FD0A113D4A96" version="1" lang="sv" srclng="en"?>
```

This is somewhere in the middle of the xml file

```
<row>
<entry colname="col1" valign="middle" align="left">"Bending method" </entry>
<entry colname="col2" valign="middle" align="left">another word</entry>
</row>
```

So.. this is the original regex:

```
(?<!=)”\b(.+?)\b”(?! \[)
```

Replacement:

```
“1”
```

Problem:
As the metadata “concept.dtd” and “map.dtd” are part of the file, I don’t want to replace their quotation marks in order not to change anything crucial. So I tried rewriting the regex:

```
(?<!=)”\b(.+?[\.d])\b”(?! \[)
```

It almost works: “concept.dtd” and “map.dtd” are skipped, most of the terms between quotation marks are found, but not all: “Bending method” is not found, for example.

What am I missing? Any help or opinions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question is unnecessarily long, but doesn't clearly state the problem, e.g. please just provide a single precise testcase with a string which you want to match, and a regexp which you expect to match that string but doesn't.  If you make the question easier to understand, you are more likely to get a helpful answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Tried to shorten it :)

Comment: Thanks, this is WAY better!  However, now it's not clear what tools / languages you have available, or are willing to use.  You previously mentioned Powergrep, but what about something like Python or Ruby?  It would be easy to solve in either of these in a cleaner manner which doesn't try to shoe-horn the solution into a single regexp.

Comment: Which language do you use ?

Comment: Eh, well, I fell pretty stupid. I have no idea. I'm probably the biggest noob around on this website ;-)

We're working with Powergrep, which uses regexes to find / filter /... large collections of xml files. Did this help to answer your question?

Maybe I should split the regex into multiple lookups?

Comment: Did you notice that the first time you mention *bending method* in your question, it is followed by a curly quotation ? Is it the same in  the xml files ?

Comment: Argh, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.
Will edit the question and provide a sample of the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last answers, here is a regexp that can help you:

```
(?<=<entry)[^>]+>[^<>]*?(".+?")[^<>]*?(?=<\x2Fentry>)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/lX2cU3

#### Discussion

I assume that you have one serie of words between straight quotations and that there are no carriage returns ou line feeds inside an `<entry>` node.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot :) But... unfortunately, it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @AnnDH Can you retry my regex by replacing curly quotations with straight quotations ?

Comment: Somehow, it only finds strings that are _not_ between quotation marks... So out of my original first lines, namely 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd"[
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd"[
]>`

only the following gets highlighted (found):

`" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "`

and Powergrep wants to replace it by `“ ”`. Hmm :/

Comment: @AnnDH Can you post a sample of your xml in your question please ? This will get us to the solution faster.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question :-) Sorry - I'm not used to working with anything like regexes or codes, so I'm not sure what you need to help me out. But thanks, really :)

Comment: @AnnDH Do you want to change quotations inside `<entry>` nodes only ?

Comment: Oh wow, I never realized that >< Yes, of course, well spotted :) Only the strings inside the `<entry>` code.

Comment: @AnnDH Check my new answer

Comment: Thank you so much! This is _almost_ what I needed. The regex finds all the words I need, but also numbers. I'll need to rework the replacement regex (bc now, the replacement looks like `“"concept"”`) But you really helped me out. I'll try to fix the small bugs myself :-) It's very close, thanks again!

Comment: I think I found it :-) It matches all the words I wanted it to match, the replacement looks just fine and there are no numbers to be found (before, the regex also found e.g. `4,7"` I've changed it into `(?<=<entry)[^>]+>[^<>]*?"(.+?[^0-9])"[^<>]*?(?=<\x2Fentry>)` and this does the trick. Thanks a million for your help!